# extra line while printing process output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following python3 code to print difference of two files/directories:

```
def out_diff(arg1, arg2):
    out = subprocess.Popen(['diff', '-r', arg1, arg2], 
               stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
               stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    stdout, stderr = out.communicate()
    print(type(stdout))
    print(type(stderr))
    if len(stdout) != 0:
        print('stdout: ', arg1, arg2, stdout.decode()),  # error line
    if stderr is not None:
        print('stderr: ', arg1, arg2, stderr)
    print('end of function')

out_diff('output1', 'output2')
```

And its output is the following:

```
stdout:  output1 output2 diff: output1: No such file or directory
diff: output2: No such file or directory

end of function
```

My question is, whether or not I put a trailing comma on the stdout printing line (marked by "#"), an empty line is always printed. I don't understand why that is happening. Something should have changed based on the presence of the trailing comma.

My expectation was that since a `'\n'` was in the stdout string, then if I did NOT put a trailing comma then 2 empty lines would be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish here or what you are actually asking.

In Python 3 a trailing comma after `print()` doesn't do anything. You are probably confusing this with the behavior of `print` (without parentheses) in Python 2, where a trailing comma said to omit the final newline.

In any event, redirecting standard error to standard output and then examining both standard output and standard error seems like a very confused thing to do.

Moreover, you really should not use `Popen` when `run` will do.

```
def out_diff(arg1, arg2):
    out = subprocess.run(['diff', '-r', arg1, arg2], 
               stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
               stderr=subprocess.PIPE,   # Notice how this is distinct
               check=False,              # Be explicit that we tolerate errors from diff
               universal_newlines=True)  # Decode text
    print(type(out.stdout))
    print(type(out.stderr))
    if len(out.stdout) != 0:
        print('stdout: {0} {1} {2}'.format(arg1, arg2, out.stdout), end='')
    if len(out.stderr) != 0:
        print('stderr: {0} {1} {2}'.format(arg1, arg2, stderr), end='')
    print('end of function')
```

Notice how `print(string, end='')` will omit the final newline in Python 3.

Anyway, the proper way to interact programmatically with `diff` is to examine its exit status (`out.returncode`) instead of its output.

Comment: For (much) more on how to use `subprocess` properly, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538

Comment: Thanks very much. You caught several errors in my code at one shot. Can you add a brief explanation on the check=False, I did not quite understand that.

Comment: `check=True` says to fail and raise an exception if the subprocess returns a non-zero exit code. I added `check=False` just to make it explicit that we really don't want that (`diff` will return "failure" if there are differences). The linked answer explains this in a lot more detail.

Comment: BTW, out.returncode != 0 only if stderr, eg when a file is missing. If both files exist and there is a diff, then outcode is still 0, so we also have to check for len(out.stdout)!=0.

Comment: That's not my experience. `diff` returns `out.returncode = 1` if both files exist and there is a difference. Are you on some wacky platform like Windows?

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, `print` is a function that always returns `None`. By adding a comma after the call, you create and immediately discard the tuple `(None,)` instead of just `None`. This makes no difference in your code whatsoever, besides slowing it down imperceptibly.

To suppress the newline that `print` normally appends to its output, you will need to pass in the keyword-only argument `end`. `end` defaults to `\n`. Set it to `''` instead:

```
print('stdout: ', arg1, arg2, stdout.decode(), end='')
```

As you pointed out correctly, `stdout.decode()` will most likely already contain a trailing newline.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I accepted the other one because it was more detailed, especially it pointed out my mistake of adding comma at the end which was a python2 feature, and advised to use run instead.

Comment: @R71. No worries. I appreciate the feedback.